# OpenGl es 2.0 multitexture problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es, glsl

I need to load two textures into a shader, but when the application starts, the first texture is displayed correctly, and the second is just a black square

Load Texture

```java
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Activation Textures

```java
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgram.posHandle);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgram.texcordHandle);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderProgram.posHandle,3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vbuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderProgram.texcordHandle,2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, tbuffer);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTexid());
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.texHandle, texture.getTexid());

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, blend.getTexid());
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.tex01Handle, blend.getTexid());

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ibuffer);
```

Fragment Shader

```c
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tx;
uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform float alpha;
varying vec2 v_tex;
void main(){
    vec4 t = texture2D(tex, v_tex);
    vec4 te = texture2D(tx, v_tex);
    gl_FragColor = te;
}
```

[First sampler2D tex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F2ld.png)
[image]

[Second sampler2D tx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJMw1.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBindTexture.xhtml) binds a texture to the specified target in the current texture unit. The current texture unit is a global state and is selected by [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml).
You have to select the texture before binding the texture. Changing the texture unit has no effect to the currently bound textures:

```java
# bind "texture" to texture unit 0
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTexid());

# bind "blend" to texture unit 1
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);    
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, blend.getTexid());
```

Furthermore, the binding point between the texture object and the texture sampler uniform is the texture unit. Thus the texture object has to be bound to the texture unit and the number of the texture unit has to be assigned to the texture sampler uniform (0 for `GL_TEXTURE0`, 1 for `GL_TEXTURE1`). e.g:

```java
GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.texHandle, 0);   // 0 means GL_TEXTURE0
GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.tex01Handle, 1); // 1 means GL_TEXTURE1
```